# Connecting to redis-server using a website-type URL in Python

Tags: docker, redis, redis-py

I have this URL, suppose `https://abc.xyz.net/pqr/redis`. Basically, this is the url made for serving ipaddress:port of redis-server. I want to ask how can I connect to such type of url, using python.

Just an additional info, the redis-server is running on a container. Please suggest anything, which can make this workable, other than exposing ip-address and port of the server.

Comment: Redis doesn't speak the HTTP protocol, and doesn't have URL-style paths.  Can you give a more concrete example of what inputs you have, and what code you already have to try to connect?

Comment: So, it won't be possible to connect redis through such urls?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about different layer of computer network.

HTTP/HTTPS with URL, is L7 protocol, which using DNS server to translate URL into target host ip address and then build up TCP/IP socket.

Redis connection is native TCP/IP connection, which generally considered as L4 protocol.

So redis connection will not handle http/https encoding and DNS parising, which is not possible to use URL to connect.